# split column value of sql server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

There is a column "AppendedData" in "Route" table . It stores data in this format

```
-------------
ID |  AppendedData
1  |  abc : xyz
2  |  123a : gvk
--------------
```

What I want is to write a search query over this "AppendedData" in where clause by spliting/substring it in two parts . The part before ":" is to be used in matching the values.

The current application that i am working is an old one so I can't go for writing an stored procedure . So what I am left is writing query in c# and executing it and returning a datable. So how can I do this in c#??

I was trying this in sql server till now it is returning the second part ie, after ":".

my query:

```
select SUBSTRING(AppendedData,CHARINDEX(':',AppendedData)+1, 100) from  route
```

Comment: why do you need to do in C#? What result do you want to get?

Comment: Can `AppendedData` contain more than one `:`?

Comment: @tim no there will be only one ":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

In `SQL`

```
declare @route  TABLE
(  
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [AppendedData] varchar (50) NOT NULL  
)   

insert into @route values (1, 'abc : xyz') 
insert into @route values (2, '123a : gvk') 

select SUBSTRING(AppendedData,CHARINDEX(':',AppendedData)+1, 100) from @route where             SUBSTRING(AppendedData,1, CHARINDEX(':', AppendedData)-1) = '123a'
```

In `C#`

```
var lstRoutes = new List<Route>
{
    new Route {ID = 1, AppendedData = "abc : xyz"},
    new Route {ID = 2, AppendedData = "123a : gvk"},
                                   };
var result = lstRoutes.Where(r1 => r1.AppendedData.Split(':')[0].Trim() == "abc")
            .Select(r => new { r.ID, right = r.AppendedData.Split(':')[1] });
```

Comment: thanks prasad it worked well in Sql server, Let see if it goes well in C# too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the first part of the value, you can try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Route WHERE AppendData LIKE '123a :%'
```

and it would match your row with ID 2.

Comment: But what if the value would be `123aa:123a:123b` instead? The second token should match if he searches "123a", maybe already the first(depends on requirement: contains or equals). Your query would not find any.

Comment: That depends on the form of the value. This "The part before : is to be used in matching the values." sounds to me like there is only one : separator.